# Angular 6 ERROR in ./node_modules/@telerik/kendo-intl/dist/es/cldr/territory.js

Tags: kendo-ui, angular6, npm-install

I am working on an Angular 6 project. I was installing a plug in for xlsx and file-save and after ng build I have started getting this error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@telerik/kendo-intl/dist/es/cldr/territory.js 13:9
Module parse failed: Identifier 'territoryFromName' has already been declared (13:9)
    You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
    | }
    |
    > function territoryFromName(name, identity) {
    |     var likelySubtags = cldr.supplemental.likelySubtags;
    |     var parts = name.split("-");
```

I deleted contents of node modules and did npm install. Again after ng build, same error.
Then I ran

```
npm install --save '@telerik/kendo-intl';
```

Now I am getting:

```
npm ERR! Error while executing:
npm ERR! C:\Program Files\Git\cmd\git.EXE ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/telerik/kendo-intl'.git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
```

I tried running cmd prompt with Admim rights but has not helped. please help!

Comment: How can I install version @1.4.2? I think latest could be having some issues

Answer (score 0):

Fixed issue by manually editing file territory.js (node_modules@telerik\kendo-intl\dist\es\cldr). Removed function territoryFromName(name) and saved and did ng build and worked!